# Revert Rally description to the last revision

Tags: rally

I accidentally changed the description of user story and saved it. It was really long description and I want to revert it to the last revision. I tried finding out options to get it. But it seems like rally doesn't provide anything like this directly. And I will have to access the revision description using the rally rest api. Can someone help me out in telling the API or any other pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer to this. If the old descripiton is too long this is what you will get in the RevisionHistory:

```
DESCRIPTION changed [
value too long to display]
```

or from WS API when accessing revisions endpoint:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/revision?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1234&query=(User = your_user@your_domain.com)&fetch=true&start=1&pagesize=200&order=CreationDate DESC
```

`DESCRIPTION changed [<br/>value too long to display]`

Rally historic data is available from [LookbackAPI](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual). But per [Unavailable Fields](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual/unavailablefields) section of the manual, big/rich text fields is not captured  (Description, Notes, etc.)